# Unbounded delay but no positive rate

Tags: uppaal

I have created this UPPAAL specification: https://pastebin.com/v4AkYUuy

But when running the query:

```
simulate 100 [<=500] { time }
```

I get the error:

```
Location Person.Rijssen has unbounded delay but no positive rate.
```

I have searched for hours, but UPPAAL does not have a great documentation.

[Person](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJ94x.png) [Car](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfJ5s.png) [Train](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXbdO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just add an exponential rate to that location. 
Uppaal attempts to use exponential distribution when there is no upper bound for delay, but it does not know the rate, hence an error message. 
See also Uppaal SMC tutorial.